# Mocking only partial of the test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am testing a method that will throw an exception almost immediately if the argument passed to the method is above some business rule limit.

The class that I test has dependencies so I mock them. However, since the exception will be thrown almost immediately am I allowed (is it correct) to only mock the things I need? Or do I need to specify the whole test?

I expect the exception to be thrown so do I need to mock all the objects and set up return values etc?

What is correct in these situations? And is it wrong to do both an verify and an assert in the same test?

Comment: Be pragmatic: does the test check that an exception is thrown when it should be thrown, and does it fail if this exception is not thrown by the method? Yes, so it's fine. Is your test doing an assert and a verify in the same method useful and readable? Yes, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be great if you can have some code samples. BUT, as I understood you question, you are [Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) a method, and it will throw an exception immediately after checking some kind of a business rule. You also have dependencies injected to this class (SUT - System Under Test). Those dependencies are mocked/stubbed in your Unit Test, but because of the exception being thrown immediately, you are not sure that mocking everything is a good idea or not.

Typically, with any Unit Test, you want to be absolutely sure that your Unit Test only contains what it needs, but nothing else. If you are mocking stubbing stuff in your Unit Test and they have not been used during your Test execution within your SUT, then

a. Your Tests can be harder to maintain, and harder to read as it may not be easy to figure it out what the test has really being used and what the test is actually doing.

b. Your Test can fail for the wrong reason. For example, your SUT works exactly the way you expect to work, but because of unwanted dependencies is being mocked, any refactoring and fail your test for the wrong reason. This is also called [false positive](http://xunitpatterns.com/false%20positive.html) test.

What you should try to achieve is to write a separate Unit Test to verify the exception scenario. This test would only have the dependencies injected to make your rule violate so you can test the exception scenario. All your other tests would have dependencies injected to accordingly to make those tests satisfy as possible.

Comment: I would disagree actually. The world is not black or white, but this approach is moving too close to the white box testing in my opinion. When writing a unit test we are checking the method behavior - whether it fulfills the contract or not. The fact that exception is thrown in the begining of the method should be of no meaning for the test. What you say about failing for wrong reason would actually apply when somebody will refactor the method moving the exception to the end which could cause the test to fail because of unsatisfied dependency. What I do is always provide all dependencies.

Comment: You probably misunderstood my answer. It is not only 'moving of exception' to the end causing it to fail, it is also the scemantic violation cause the test to fail. Lesser dependencies into a perticular unit test is always the norm and it is the standard. It is your opinion and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no ultimate answer for this question, but as I also stated in a comment for Spocks answer, what I do is always provide all dependencies that the class under test needs no matter the particular test will ever make use of it or not. Here's why I do so:

Basically the implementation may change but my test should still pass if the expected behavior is satisfied. Note, that not using a dependency may be explicitely an expected behavior. In this case I think it could be omitted.

At least when using TDD (where you should write your test first) when you write the test you do not know when exactly the exception will be thrown. Unless you don't have explicit behavioral requirement for that, this should be completely transparent from the test perspective.